# Long Polling client-side "Time Gap" Between 2 Pollings

Tags: javascript, ajax, websocket, long-polling

Assume I have a server support client side long polling.
then my client-side code is like this:

```
var polling = function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/polling"
    }).done(function(data) {
        // polling again
        polling();
        // process the pushed data
        ...
    });
}
polling();
```

this should work when i wanna push something to the client while the client continuously polling to "/polling".

however, you may notice that there are "time gap" between the client received a pushed data and next polling reaches the server. data in this "time gap" would be lost.

there are kinds of server side workarounds to avoid this problem.
but i want to know if there are any workarounds in the client-side?
such as:
* could the client keeps the long polling request always connected? i find Gmail should do some tricks like this. i chat in gtalk but don't see the "/bind" request interrupts.
* should ajax receives in-complete data while transfering? then the connection can be connected forever.
* should websocket works? if so, what can i do without HTML5?

Comment: um, why would you have a time gap? Shouldn't your session, request know when the last time information was returned?

Comment: @epascarello, yes server knows when the last polling. however, when the server had something to push while in the gap of 2 pollings, the server should cache/persist the data for a while when the subsequent polling reaches. but if there is no gap, the server just do not need the cache.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider something like [Pusher](http://pusher.com/), it will make your life much easier when dealing with such things (because they give you a library to handle all of this in a nice package).